# RabbitMQ 405 RESOURCE_LOCKED - cannot obtain access to locked queue

Tags: rabbitmq

rabbitMQ version: 3.11.8 , MassTransit: 8.0.1. 
I have a queue with this config:  
`x-queue-type:quorum, x-single-active-consumer:true, durable:true`

sometimes I need to do the action: *GetMessage(s)* in the Management panel.
but now with this queue I got this exeption:

> 405 RESOURCE_LOCKED - cannot obtain access to locked queue 'myQueue' in vhost 'xxx'. basic.get operations are not supported by quorum queues with single active consumer
> [image]

- usaully I need to read messages from errpr_queue that Masstransit created.

I've searched for that, and I found just some solutions for exclusive queues- for example [issue 1](https://github.com/StackStorm/st2/issues/4164) and  [issue 2](https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-server/issues/2164).

but I couldn't find any solution for 'cannot obtain access to locked queue'

Answer (score 0):

So, you've requested a single active consumer on the queue. And when you try to get messages in the console, it reports that the queue is locked.

Seems like that would be expected behavior, and it's telling you as much in the error message.

Comment: I agree with you. but I've stopped my .net application and absolutely hadn't any connection to my RabbiMQ server. and you know  that sometimes we need to get error messages. otherwise how can I see error messages?

Comment: I have this problem, too. when we use the mode 'single-active-consumer' in a queue with type of quorum, how can we fetch the messages (for example my_error_queue messages) in the RabbitMQ management dashboard?